# Создание тестовой оплаты через инлайн клавиатуру в aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Мне надо, чтобы при выборе варианта доставки в *inline*-клавиатуре пользователю приходила клавиатура с предложением оплатить, у меня есть два куска кода (первый - до оплаты, второй - то, что должно происходить после выбора варианта доставки). Я просто не понимаю, как их можно соединить.

Первый код (до оплаты):

```py
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher, FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils import executor
from config import TOKEN
    
bot = Bot(token = TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

class Games(StatesGroup):
    game = State()
    delivery = State()


genres_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
genres_keyboard.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton('Action', callback_data='Action'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('MMO', callback_data='MMO'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('RPG', callback_data='RPG')
)

delivery_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
delivery_keyboard.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton('Доставка курьером', callback_data='courier'),
    InlineKeyboardButton('Самовывоз', callback_data='pickup')
)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()
    await message.answer('Здравствуйте!\nВы находитесь в магазине игр\nВыберите жанр игры:', reply_markup=genres_keyboard)
    await Games.game.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Games.game)
async def get_games(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['game'] = call.data
    await call.message.edit_text(text=f'Вы успешно выбрали жанр "{call.data}", теперь необходимо выбрать вариант доставки!', reply_markup=delivery_keyboard)
    await Games.next()

@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Games.delivery)
async def process_delivery(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['delivery'] = 'Доставка курьером' if call.data == 'courier' else 'Самовывоз'
    await call.message.edit_text(text=f'Вы выбрали жанр "{data["game"]}" и вариант доставки "{data["delivery"]}"')
    await state.finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Вот второй код (после выбора варианта доставки):

```py
import logging
import asyncio
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command

# настройки бота
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# инициализация бота и диспетчера
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

# состояния FSM
class OrderForm(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_delivery = State()
    waiting_for_payment = State()

# обработчик команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Это тестовый бот для оплаты заказов. Нажми на кнопку, чтобы начать.", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начать", callback_data="start")
            ]
        ]
    ))

# обработчик нажатия на кнопку "Начать"
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'start')
async def process_callback_start(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Выберите способ доставки:", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton(text="Доставка курьером", callback_data="delivery_courier")
            ],
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton(text="Самовывоз", callback_data="delivery_pickup")
            ]
        ]
    ))
    await OrderForm.waiting_for_delivery.set()

# обработчик нажатия на кнопку "Доставка курьером" или "Самовывоз"
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in ['delivery_courier', 'delivery_pickup'], state=OrderForm.waiting_for_delivery)
async def process_callback_delivery(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    delivery_method = callback_query.data
    await state.update_data(delivery_method=delivery_method)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f"Вы выбрали {delivery_method}.", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оплатить", callback_data="pay"),
                InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отмена", callback_data="cancel")
            ]
        ]
    ))
    await OrderForm.waiting_for_payment.set()

# обработчик нажатия на кнопку "Оплатить" или "Отмена"
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data in ['pay', 'cancel'], state=OrderForm.waiting_for_payment)
async def process_callback_payment(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    payment_method = callback_query.data
    if payment_method == 'pay':
        data = await state.get_data()
        delivery_method = data.get('delivery_method')
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, f"Вы выбрали {delivery_method} и оплату через Qiwi. Введите номер телефона для оплаты:")
        await OrderForm.next()
    else:
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Вы отменили оплату.")
        await state.finish()

# обработчик ввода номера телефона для оплаты
@dp.message_handler(state=OrderForm.waiting_for_payment)
async def process_payment_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    payment_number = message.text
    # здесь должна быть логика для оплаты через Qiwi
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Оплата прошла успешно. Номер телефона: {payment_number}")
    await state.finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй пример не предоставляет выбора способа оплаты. Если вы хотите реализовывать несколько вариантов оплаты, то необходимо добавить их выбор после нажатия на кнопку `Оплатить`. Но если взять, как вы и хотели, идею второго примера и добавить его к первому, то это будет выглядеть так:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher, FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils import executor
from config import TOKEN

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Games(StatesGroup):
    game = State()
    delivery = State()
    accept = State()
    phone = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.delete()
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton('Action', callback_data='Action'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('MMO', callback_data='MMO'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('RPG', callback_data='RPG')
    )
    await message.answer('Здравствуйте!\nВы находитесь в магазине игр\nВыберите жанр игры:', reply_markup=keyboard)
    await Games.game.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Games.game)
async def get_games(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['game'] = call.data
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton('Доставка курьером', callback_data='courier'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('Самовывоз', callback_data='pickup')
    )
    await call.message.edit_text(text='Выберите вариант доставки:', reply_markup=keyboard)
    await Games.next()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Games.delivery)
async def process_delivery(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['delivery'] = 'Доставка курьером' if call.data == 'courier' else 'Самовывоз'
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
        InlineKeyboardButton('Оплатить', callback_data='pay'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('Отмена', callback_data='cancel')
    )
    await call.message.edit_text(text='Теперь вы можете перейти к <u>Оплате</u> или <u>Отменить заказ</u>', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=keyboard)
    await Games.next()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Games.accept)
async def process_accept(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if call.data == 'pay':
        await call.message.edit_text(text='Оплата через QIWI.\nВведите номер телефона для оплаты:')
        await Games.next()
    else:
        await call.message.edit_text(text='Вы отменили оплату')
        await state.finish()


@dp.message_handler(state=Games.phone)
async def process_phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['phone'] = message.text
    # Здесь пишите валидацию номера телефона и логику для оплаты через Qiwi.
    # Для проверки выведем полученные ранее данные от пользователя.
    await message.answer(text=f'Жанр: {data["game"]}\nСпособ доставки: {data["delivery"]}\nНомер телефона: {data["phone"]}')
    await state.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: как можно сделать, чтобы здесь проходила тестовая оплата?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под "тестовой оплатой"?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/video/preview/4441497764287727773 таймкод 10:39, вот что то типа такого, если через QIWI невозможно так, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать